# Least Upper Bound in Lattice

Tags: relations, order-theory, equivalence-relations

I am studying about Lattice in Relations and came across this example in a video lecture in which we have to find weather the given **Hasse** diagram is Join Semi Lattice or not.
The Diagram is given below :

[image]

When considered the pair {a, b} the upper bounds of these are {c, e, d} as I found and is true as far as I know.  My doubt here is that how the Least Upper Bound for them is not c or d but its *null* ?
As observed the points c and  d are below e.

Comment: From what you already calculated, a least upper bound of $\{a,b\}$ must be the smallest element of $\{c,d,e\}$. If this subset does not have a smallest element, then $a$ and $b$ do not have a join. Note that the exercise allows for this possibility.

Comment: @MarcOlschok my doubt is how to the smallest element of  {c, d, e} is null set ?

Comment: The question is: does the set $\{c,d,e\}$ have a smallest element or not?  This is easy to check because there are only three possible candidates.

Comment: but then why is the answer null ? @MarcOlschok

Comment: I do not understand. 'null' is not an answer at all. There are two possible answers: (1) $a$ and $b$ have a least upper bound. (2) $a$ and $b$ do not have a least upper bound.

Comment: @MarcOlschok null is the answer given in my book

Comment: If the answer was null, then what was the question?  As an answer to "Is this a join semilattice?" or to "Do $a$ and $b$ have a least upper bound?", "null" does not make any sense.

Comment: the question was to find the Least Upper bound if any @MarcOlschok

Comment: The author probably intends "null" to mean "there is no least upper bound of $\{a,b\}$, not, "the least upper bound of $\{a,b\}$ is null".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The poset with the above Hasse diagram is not a join semilattice (in particular it is not a lattice), because $a$ and $b$ do not have a least upper bound.

By definition a least upper bound of $a$ and $b$ would be a smallest element
of the set $S = \{ c,d,e \}$ of common upper bounds of $a$ and $b$.

A smallest element $m \in S$ would in particular need to to satisfy
$m \leq c$ and $m \leq d$. But no element of $S$ can satisfy both inequalities.

Comment: thanks for answering @Marc Olschok